# Howto change current user password?

Tags: windows-server-2012, remote-desktop

...when logged into a Server via remote Desktop?

I see no way to Access Windows security. In "old" 2008 R2 there was a "Windows Security" entry in the start menu when coming via RDP.

In the new Metro Start Menu, the username context menu allows me to lock the Computer or log out - but not Change the Password.

Yes, I can go through user Management, but this is not something I want people to do. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `CTRL-ALT-END` to send a `CTRL-ALT-DEL` to the remote system. That'll get you a 'Change a password' link.

Comment: Bingo, that was it. Was unaware of that Keyboard shortcut. Great ;) Thanks.